# The use of >> operator in a logical construct with Gurobi

Tags: python, if-statement, constraints, gurobi

I am going through someone else's code (optimization using Gurobi) and I am puzzled:

```
x = model.addVars(A, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name=['x_'+str(i)+'_'+str(j) for i in V for j     in V if i != j])
u1 = model.addVars(N, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name=["Dummy_Quantity_"+str(i) for i in     N])
u2 = model.addVars(N, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name=["Dummy_Time_U2_"+str(i) for i in     N])
u3 = model.addVars(N, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name=["Dummy_Time_U3_"+str(i) for i in     N]) 
u4 = model.addVars(N, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name=["Dummy_Time_U4_"+str(i) for i in N])

model.setObjective(sum(x[i, j]*dist[i, j] for i, j in A), GRB.MINIMIZE)

# If the truck goes from i to j points then the truck's current garbage volume is     given by the garbage 
# collected until point i + garbage produced at j'th neighborhood:
for i, j in A:
    if i != 0 and j != 0:
        model.addConstr((x[i, j] == 1) >> (u1[i]+q[j] == u1[j]))
```

What does ">>" do here? Usually, ">>" is used for bitwise operations. Is it a mistake (code compilation is OK - no errors)

The meaning here is that if a truck travels from site I to site j (binary variable =1) then the garbage amount increases as described in the comment

Is there a better way rather than using >> ?

Comment: Python allows operators to be overloaded (e.g. `+` is addition for numbers, concatenation for strings and lists). So Gurobi may have redefined `>>` for its constraint class.

Comment: Hmm.  You're assuming that they might have overridden the `==` operator to produce a type that behaves kind of like a Boolean but has overridden `>>`.  That violates the "principle of least astonishment" in so many ways that I'd be shocked if any professional programmer did so.  But, it's not impossible.

Answer (score 1):

This is an indicator constraint as explained here: [Model.addGenConstrIndicator](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_model_agc_indicator.html)

These constraints are used to model whether a certain condition needs to be fulfilled depending on the value of another binary variable. This is useful, for example, to model the opening of a new factory or storage location.

In that specific case

```
model.addConstr((x[i, j] == 1) >> (u1[i]+q[j] == u1[j]))
```

`u1[i]+q[j] == u1[j]` is only enforced if `x[i, j] == 1`. Otherwise, the constraint may be violated.

Comment: #mattmilten Thanks! I was not sure because the format looks weird. 1. the use of >>. 2. (u1[i]+q[j] == u1[j])) rather than ( u1[j]== u1[i]+q[j])

Comment: You may flip the equation around - it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Do the truth table.

```
A  B    A >> B
--------------
0  0    0
1  0    1
0  1    0
1  1    0
```

So, for boolean values, (A >> B) is equivalent to (A and not B), but produces an integer result. I would call this overly clever, and would have called it out in a code review.  I and would have written it this way to make the intent more clear:

```
int((x[i, j] == 1) and not (u1[i]+q[j] == u1[j]))
```

Comment: Tim the purpose of the operator is: if x[I,j]==1 THEN (u1[i]+q[j] == u1[j])). is it possible to keep this meaning and NOT using >>?

Comment: I don't believe that.  Do you have a reference?